# How to change to new themes in PyCharm?

Tags: themes, ide

so I installed these PyCharm themes here
https://github.com/d1ffuz0r/pycharm-themes/blob/master/README.md

Installed into a random folder, but where do I put these themes so I can change them in PyCharm?

Currently I still only see default, and Darcula.

Comment: its Darcula actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out via the author on github
https://github.com/d1ffuz0r/pycharm-themes/issues/3

In the end, the themes look terrible, and Dracula is still the best for PyCharm imho.

Answer (score 12):

`File` -> `Import Settings` -> select the .jar file and restart PyCharm.

If it isn't applied automatically you can select it in `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Colors & Fonts`.

Comment: This must be the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it's merely a workaround to replace the existing Default and Dracula themes.

Comment: It's a "workaround" to replace every setting in PyCharm. If you're only interested in "Default and Dracula themes" it will also do the job.

Answer (score 8):

I've stumbled into this question while searching for the same issue. 2 years have passed after this question was asked and in the meantime PyCharm has reached v. 5.0.3.

Unfortunately the GitHub link provided in the post above was not so illuminating, at least for me, so I started investigating on my own among PyCharm folders in Windows (mine is 7 Pro, bu I thik this applies also for other versions).

Here's what I discovered:

- There's a particular place in user's folder, from where PyCharm gets information about themes: its location is:
    %USERPROFILE%.PyCharm50\config\colors\

  To discover the exact path, just run a Command Prompt and type "set" to list environment variables; look for USERPROFILE value and you're done (usually it's *c:\users\UserName*)

WHAT DID I DO:

- Download a theme from here: [http://color-themes.com/?view=index][1] (e.g. "Cobalt"), saved to a temporary folder
- using any zip-compatible program, such as 7zip, WinZip or Total Commander (which really rocks :) ), unzip the .jar file in the config folder. Make sure you select to unzip recursive folders!
- (re)Start PyCharm, and you should see your new theme applied. If not, go to Configuration (Alt-F7), Editor >> Colors & Fonts section and click Scheme Pull-down: the new them should be listed there.

Happy Pythoning, 
Max - Italy

Answer (score 3):

As of the most recent version of PyCharm (2017.2) this process is a lot more simplified.

On a Mac:
    **Preferences** | **Editor** | **Color Scheme** - Click the settings cog next to `Scheme` and select **Import Scheme...** Then select the `.icls` file for the theme you want to add.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler in 2021 (I'm PyCharm 2020.3.3), if you are just looking for a pre-made theme:

1. Open Project Settings (Ctrl-Alt-S)
2. Select the Plugins section and type the word ***'theme'*** in the Marketplace search box:

[image]

3. Pick the theme(s) you like and click the *install* button.

Nowadays, there is a big number of choices around, so you probably find one that is just good for you (it can be customized as you like, anyway).